# Photogrammetry model turns matte black after adding modifiers after using sculpt tool

Tags: photogrammetry

[image]My Photogrammetry model turns matte black after I have been in sculpt mode and then try to add a Modifier (Remesh). I cannot get my texture back on my model once this has happened. This fault has never occurred before so I have no idea why it is happening now.

If I avoid using the sculpt tool but directly use Modifiers, there is no issue. However, I will have a stack of .blend files by the end of finishing one model if I need to keep saving a .blend and open up a new to keep working on my progression. Has anyone encountered this before? Blender version 2.82.7.

Comment: If you're using dyntopo (or remesh) the UV maps are automatically discarded, but you should get a prompt beforehand

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: FYI you can use an UV project or Data transfer modifier afterwards or even bake the uvs from the base mesh to the sculpted one. I suggest looking into that if you want to go down that road